# Using Home and Menu in a German App (from English)

Tags: english-to-german

We are building an app in German from our default English version. From the post below it looks like I am ok to leave "Home" in place. What should I do with Menu, on our Dutch version we just left this as Menu.

Would "Menu" be ok in the context of a drop-down menu for an app? Or should I change it slightly to include an umlaut? eg Menü

On the product videos, we also currently have the title "Product Video". Would this be ok left at that? Or should I use "Produkt-Video" (from Google Translate)

[Comparison between equivalent words meaning "home" in German if used on websites](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10648/comparison-between-equivalent-words-meaning-home-in-german-if-used-on-websites)

Comment: Use "Produktvideo".

Comment: Thanks Eller, just to confirm "Produktvideo" with no dash and cap letter for Video?

Comment: Yes. It's an established word.

Comment: In an app I would expect and appreciate it if you stick with the convention for these links: use three dots for "Menu" and a house icon for "Home". More space-efficient and impossible to misunderstand.

Comment: @KilianFoth As you are talking about Android: three dots as menu are obsolete for a couple of years.

Comment: @Eller Not really. While the "global" menu has mostly been replaced by the navigation drawer (a counter-example is "Google Authenticator", which doesn't use a burger menu, but still the "three dots" menu), there are scenarios, where the "three dots" menus are still used. For example in lists with options for every list entry or on cards. The current Instagram app would be an example for this.

Answer (score 4):

If *Startseite* for *Home* is too long, using *Start* is also ok.

*Menü* is the German term for *Menu*, also in "computer speak".

*Product Video* can either be *Produktvideo* or *Produkt-Video*. The hyphenated version is also ok, even though *Produktvideo* is a proper and understood compound noun.

Please note that in apps (Android, iOS, etc.) there may be other OS-specific ways of achieving what you want. Please make sure to stick with the OS's way to avoid confusion for the user.

---

Please note that the last paragraph is the result of the fact that I'm a software developer and I disagree with the current trend of calling every piece of software an "app".

To me, an app is a small piece of software **specifically designed** to run on a **smartphone** (=> Android App, iOS App, etc.). Everything else (web sites, desktop applications, server side services) are not apps and should not be called "apps"! Even though "app" is just an abbreviation of "application" I do consider them very different things from a software design point of view.

Comment: +1 for your last statement on the inflationary usage of the word "app"

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recommend to use:

- Startseite for Home
- Menü for Menu (or Navigation)

But you could also leave it as it is, in this case you just have to remember not everyone is as good in English as others.

Comment: Thanks, thats great - what do you think on Product Video?  (Produkt-Video)

Comment: Yeah this is okay